# The loop in my imacro code does not work. How to fix it?

Tags: imacros

This imacro script is used to follow pinterest followers.As the imacros Freeware Limit is 100, I want to make a loop and run this imacros for all day. If I can make 10 loop and Freewarelimit loop is 100 so 10*100 = 1000 times. Please someone correct my code.

My current code runs but it bypasses the loop. 
URL : https://www.pinterest.com/belhoussainedri/followers/

This is the URL you should try to run the imacros on.

```
VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES


SET !LOOP 0
SET INIT 100
SET STEP 3

TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Follow
WAIT SECONDS=2

SET VALUE EVAL("{{INIT}}+{{STEP}}*{{!LOOP}}")
```

I want the code to run all day. Without any pinterest follow limit exceeding

Answer (score 0):

use an earlier version of IMacros like version 9.0.3 which supports javascript running, you can use the below code, to run the same macro code any number of times as you want.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Follow"+"\n";
macro +="TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Follow"+"\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=2";

///The triggering part
var totalNumbers = 1000
for (var i=1;i<totalNumbers;i++) {
    iimPlay(macro)
}
```